# How to create a Google Analytics view to restrict tracked pages to a subdirectory?

Tags: google-analytics

I'd like to create a Google Analytics view that tracks only pages in a subdirectory of the property.

There is a [similar question here](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/9196/google-analytics-best-way-to-separate-stats-for-subdirectories), but none of the answers detail the steps to create a Segment for the subdirectory.

How do I create a Segment for the subdirectory for my custom View?

Help appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not a Segment I need, but a Filter for the new View.

Here’s how to set up a view filter for a subdirectory:

1. Make sure you have admin/editing access to the Google Analytics account
2. In the view column, create a new view for your subfolder
3. Implement any existing filters that you want to apply to this view as well (e.g. filtering out IPs from your office)
4. Choose a predefined filter
5. Include only traffic to the subdirectories that begin with *
6. Add your subdirectory as /subdirectory/
7. Save